# an error in my code with the word (print)

Tags: python

The problem is I typed print and it did nothing, I don't know what the issue is because this is my 3rd time writing a code, I don't think it's a good idea to continue coding with an error not fixed yet, here's the code:

```
    name_lastname = input("Hello, what is your name and last name ?")
    voulanteer_q = input("Mr/Mrs "+name_lastname+ " do you want to be a voulanteer ? yes/no \n>")
    voulanteer_q = ""
    if voulanteer_q == "yes":
    print("where ? entrance gate ? gift shop ? painting ?")***
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59sKj.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAgsq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `voulanteer_q = ""`, as it will override the user input and your logic won't work. The line above with `voulanteer_q = input(..` will contain your user's input.

Your updated code should look like below

```
name_lastname = input("Hello, what is your name and last name ?")
voulanteer_q = input("Mr/Mrs "+name_lastname+ " do you want to be a voulanteer ? yes/no \n>")
if voulanteer_q == "yes":
   print("where ? entrance gate ? gift shop ? painting ?")
```